# how can i restore two models into one session, and then save them respectively?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I've got two models, which are from the same network but with different top variable scope name, so the name of two variable sets are totally different, for example, for a w variable, one is j2e/training/w and the other is e2j/training/w . 
I'd like to load them into one session and do some interaction training and hope to save these two models respectively, kinda like dual learning...
how can i do? can i do like:

```
    .........building graph...........
    saver1 = tf.train.Saver(var_list1)
    saver2 = tf.train.Saver(var_list2)
    saver1.restore(sess, model1)
    saver2.restore(sess, model2)
```

and finally:

```
    saver1.save(sess, path1)
    saver2.save(sess, path2)
```

if so, how would the interactions between two models be restored? which model would save this part of graph? and how can i get var_list1 and var_list2?

thanks a lot..

Comment: Con you supply more info? I am trying to understand what you want to do and why. Thanks

Comment: it's a machine translation problem. the original two models are in two directions respectively, for example, j2e and e2j. and they are from the same network, just with different variable scope.  In order to try dual learning, i need to load these two models into one session, and after learning i also hope to save them respectively  just like they used to be...

Answer (score 0):

OK, try something like this:

```
def graph_e2j(var_list1):
    e2j = tf.Graph()
    saver1 = tf.train.Saver(var_list1)
    with e2j.as_default() as e2j:
            saver1.restore(sess, model1)
    return g.as_graph_def()
```

Now do a similiar function for the other model.

For the saving part you mentioned, you said it correctly as those savers point to different sets of variables

Comment: but they ought to be in one graph in one session... and I've tried it out. yeah~~the way I thought works...thx...